# hpn-ssh on ubuntu server

Tags: ssh, sshd

What is the current status of hpn-ssh on ubuntu?
It is not in the default repositories, as far as I can tell, but does anybody knows if there are any plans to add it (or decisions not to add it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no package yet , but it will soon https://launchpad.net/~w-rouesnel/+archive/openssh-hpn