# Setup OpenSSH-HPN in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [hpn-ssh on ubuntu server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96589/hpn-ssh-on-ubuntu-server)

I have setup openssh in in Ubuntu12.10. the version it shows 
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012

Does this version contain OpenSSH-HPN or do i have it install is separately. If so can some please tell me how to do it

Thanks

Comment: What is HPN? Please elaborate on that or provide a link with more information on this. Not everyone is familiar with "HPN".

Comment: http://www.psc.edu/index.php/hpn-ssh

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~w-rouesnel/+archive/openssh-hpn

Comment: hi does any body have an answer for this?

Comment: You appear to have solved your own question in your second comment, don't you? If it's still unclear to you, be more specific on what you tried, what you expected to happen and what happened instead.